# "only secured content is displayed"

Tags: security

I just had a SSL certificate installed on my drupal site using shared hosting 
and on the front page it now says "only secured content is displayed" in IE.  How do I find which content is NOT secure on this page?

Answer (score 5):

You could fire up [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what exactly IE is requesting over regular HTTP.

In Fiddler's default configuration, HTTPS requests will show up with a lock and `CONNECT` as the host.  HTTP requests will have a non-lock icon.

[image]
<sub>(source: [josh3736.net](http://josh3736.net/images/fiddlerhttps.png))</sub>

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836381/easy-way-to-determine-what-content-is-not-delivered-using-a-secure-https-connect/2836389#2836389)

Answer (score 1):

Also in chrome if you "inspect element" on a page it opens the "Elements Panel in the Dev tools.  From there chose the Network section.  As you mouse over every request the page makes it will give you the full url the page used to request it.  look for any that are not https and you will have your culprits.  Chances are you have calls to absolute urls as opposed to relative urls, so it is forcing http instead of using the implied https of the page.